# Simulating data for a multiple linear regression

Tags: distributions, multiple-regression, simulation

How can I simulate a data for multiple linear regression (one IV and more then 2 IV) when we know the skewness and kurtosis of the data?

Another question is, how can we determine the type of distribution (ex: gamma dist) based on the skewness and kurtosis? We know that for normal distribution, the skewness and kurtosis are (0,0)...

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the skewness and kurtosis of the dependent variable or of the *residuals*? If it's the former, your problem is complicated by the fact that those moments depend on the regression coefficients themselves and on moments of the IVs.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to choose some distribution - the first few moments are not enough to pin that down very well.

You might consider assuming the Pearson or the Johnson families of distributions, perhaps.

> how can we determine the type of distribution (ex: gamma dist) based on the skewness and kurtosis?

You can't, as explained above, unless you restrict yourself to only considering a family where there's a one-to-one relationship.